# Etymology of the phrase "the whole shebang"?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the phrase "the whole shebang", or "whole shebang"? I only know the term "shebang" from [a computer science standpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), but I'm not sure of any other uses of it outside of this phrase. So, I was wondering if that's where the phrase originated.

Comment: Voting to close as general reference. [The answer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=shebang&searchmode=none) is easily found via a single search.

Comment: I'm a professional computer geek and I'd never heard the "computer meaning" you cite before. In any case the phrase was in use long before Linux came along. Some people call an exclamation mark a "bang", so I'd guess that usage came from someone noticing the "bang" followed by "sh" and being reminded of the word "shebang". So whatever the origin of the phrase "the whole shebang" is ... that isn't it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest citation that I can find for *shebang* in the Unix sense is:

> 1989   Larry Wall, Post to comp.sources.bugs titled "[perl 3.0 patch #7](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.sources.bugs/xk8FQ6MuBzM)"          Perl didn't grok setuid scripts that had a space on the first line between the shebang and the interpreter name.

In this sense, *shebang* [is a shortening of *hash-bang* or *sharp-bang*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Etymology); but Larry Wall is fond of puns (for example, his book title *Programming Perl* is a pun on the title of Jon Bentley's column "Programming Pearls" in *Communications of the ACM*) so I am confident that if he was the coiner of the term he would have intended an allusion to the already existing word *shebang*.

In general use, *shebang* is fossilized in the phrase "the whole shebang" where it means "any matter of present concern; thing; business", but the *OED* notes that this developed from an earlier group of uses:

> **1. a.** A hut, shed; one's dwelling, quarters. **b.** Applied to a vehicle. **c.** A low drinking establishment, a tavern.

with first citation from 1862 ([quoted by Roaring fish in another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80059/2175)).

So this question is a fascinating example of the [recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion).

Comment: Do you have any evidence for “this question is a fascinating example”, or is that just an unsupported assertion?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're hoping for me to say here, but "example" is justified by the text of the question (OP considers possibility that *shebang* has a recent origin in computer terminology despite appearing in a phrase where its meaning is opaque); and "fascinating" is my own personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

[OED:](http://www.oed.com)

> **shebang**, *n*.
>   Pronunciation:  /ʃɪˈbæŋ/
>   Forms:  Also †**chebang**, **shee-bang**.
>   Etymology:  Of obscure origin.

If OED doesn't know the origin asking EL&U is a bit optimistic, but note that it was around in 1862

> - 1862   W. Whitman *Jrnl.* 23–31 Dec. in Specimen Days (1882–3) 27   Their shebang enclosures of bushes.

which was long before Unix.

Comment: It’s sense 3 from the OED which here applies, not sense 1 which your citation is from.

Comment: My OED has only two senses. The first is a building or vehicle, the second is "2. ‘More widely, almost any matter of present concern". What do you have for sense 3?

Comment: Sorry, I meant sense 2.  The one whose first citation is Twain.